# Allowing text in the ExtJS grid cell to overflow across multiple columns

Tags: css, extjs, grid, overflow, cell

I have a tree panel where I want some grid cell text to overflow across multiple columns instead of getting trimmed with ellipses in the end.

**Tree**

[image]

> What I really want is to be able to have this text "Text I want to
>   flowt/overflow across column B,C or D is required" to simply cross
>   Column A's right side border and show completely over next columns in
>   line. I want to reduce the width of Column A as majority of text in
>   Column A is just 3 characters wide e.g. "MYR", "TRY" etc.

**This is very easy to achieve in MS Excel**

[image]

A big thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make the x-grid-row class "relative" by position.

```
.x-grid-row {
    position: relative !important;
}
```

add **tdCls** to column definition

```
xtype : 'treecolumn',
text : 'Analyst',
dataIndex : 'text',
tdCls : 'absolute-cell-inner',
```

add css for "absolute" position for the inner text

```
.absolute-cell-inner > .x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn {
    position: absolute !important;
}
```